# Can't customize django ckeditor toolbar

Tags: django, ckeditor, toolbar, django-1.6, django-ckeditor

I installed **django-ckeditor==4.4.8** on **django1.6**

But I get a minimum of buttons in the toolbar, I tried to change the toolbar to get more options, specially to be able to add pictures

this is  what I get:

[image]

and these are my settings:

```
#ckeditor settings
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "images/"
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar':'Full',
},
```

}

---

btw I wonder what happen when you add a picture and then delete that link of picture from text editor, 
is that picture doing to be deleted?

Answer (score 5):

Try putting this in your settings file:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
   'default': {
       'toolbar_Full': [
            ['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'SpellChecker', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
            ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
            ['Smiley', 'SpecialChar'], ['Source'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
            ['Indent','Outdent'],
            ['Maximize'],
        ],
        'extraPlugins': 'justify,liststyle,indent',
   },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have this in your settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
}
```

Also this is full list  of possible options. Adding it and commenting out unnecessary things is the way to go.

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        # 'skin': 'office2013',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
            '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
                'Preview',
                'Maximize',

            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        # 'height': 291,
        # 'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            # 'devtools',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar':'full',
}
```

change the capital `F` to small `f`

This is a bit late but I figure someone else will find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Have this in your settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'none',
    },
}
```